# Question on Vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Why line integral over a vector field for a closed curve is not zero for Vector field other than conservative one..means displacement is zero in case of closed curve so I thought work done should come zero but it isn't... why.?

Answer (score 0):

An analogy: Consider a lossless electric car with perfect regeneration traveling over hilly terrain. No matter what path it takes (assuming that you didn’t run out of battery charge along the way, of course), when the car returns to its starting point the battery will have the same charge as when it started. The work done against gravity when climbing hills equals the work done by gravity in charging the battery when descending them, and most importantly, all of that work goes into changing the vehicle’s elevation and charging the battery. This is the conservative case.

In a more realistic vehicle, there are energy losses when propelling the car, and neither is regeneration 100% efficient. When the car returns to its starting point, the remaining battery charge will in general not be the same as when it started. Not all of the work done by gravity went into charging the battery, there were frictional losses that burned off some of the energy as heat, so not all of the work done by the car went directly towards changing the car’s elevation, and so on. This is the non-conservative case.